# Bootstrap 3 Background-color issue when scrolling..?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some problem in bootstrap, I develope website but after completation of website client say they dont want to responsive website.

So, I first fix the .container width to 960px !important;

It will works..!! But Problem is I am also using .row class every where row class is making responsiveness which its contains..

I want 100% width background at footer but when I resize browser & scroll horizontally it will removes the background color.

What can I do...

See Website :  [Snapshot 1](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/5K8)

When browser resize then see Whats the problem occure :  [Snapshot 2](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/5Ki)

my html code is written in bootstrap 3 :

```
<footer>    
<div class="row footercolor">
        <div class="container">  
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 ">
                  <div class="row">
                  <h5 class="undr footertitle">Lorem Ipsum</h5>
                 </div>
             </div>

             <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div class="row">
                  <h5 class="undr footertitle">QUICK LINKS</h5>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">                  
                      <ul class="footerlist list-group">

                       </ul>
                  </div>     
                  <div class="col-xs-6">  
                       <ul class="footerlist list-group">

                       </ul>
                  </div>
                  </div>
             </div>

             <div class="col-xs-4">
             <div class="row">
               <h5 class="undr footertitle">OUR NEIGHBORHOODS</h5>
                   <div class="col-xs-6">                     
                      <ul class="footerlist list-group">

                       </ul>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-xs-6">                      
                       <ul class="footerlist list-group ">

                       </ul>
                  </div>
             </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-xs-3">
                  <div class="row">
                        <h5 class="undr footertitle">GET WEEKLY LISTING UPDATES</h5>
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control">
                          <span class="input-group-addon btn-ftrbtn">Add Me</span>
                        </div>              
                  </div>
                  <div class="row"><br/></div>
                  <div class="row">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline pull-right">
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/fb.png"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/twitter.png"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/pintrest.png"></a></li>
                        </ul>                                     
                  </div>      
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
</footer>
```

& My CSS Code is :

```
.footercolor {
    background-color: #5e6872;
}
.footer{color:#c6c6c9}

.footertitle {
    font-family: 'myriad_prosemibold_condensed' !important;
    font-size: 13px!important;
    color: #fff !important;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
.footerlist li a {
    font-family: 'myriad_prolight_semicondensed' !important;
    font-size: 12px!important;
    color: #c6c6c9 !important;
    text-decoration: none
}
.footerlist li a:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
    cursor: pointer
}

.row {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important; 
}
.container{min-width:960px !important;}
```

At the last Please Give me solution for that...
Any Help will be appreciated...

Comment: They give an example here http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/ for non-responsiveness have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code to your CSS file will fix the issue.

```
html, body {
 min-width:960px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect markup for bootstrap mate....

Use **container > row > span**

Instead of :

```
<div class="row footercolor">
        <div class="container">
```

Order should be :

```
<div class="container footercolor">  <!-- notice the reverse order now -->
        <div class="row ">
```

Comment: Hi But whn i give container it will give background color on width:960px only because i give container{width:960px !important} & i want width:100% background color, Please help...!!